# Copy PDB with post-build event for Azure Functions project

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, robocopy, pdb-files

I'm struggling to copy files from the bin folder up a level using a post-build command on an Azure Functions V2 project, Core 2.2. I think there are two parts to the problem.

At the moment my command targets one specific file, because that's the one I'm having trouble with:

```
 <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
<Exec Command="(robocopy $(TargetDir)bin\ $(TargetDir) MyProject.pdb) ^&amp; IF %25ERRORLEVEL%25 LSS 8 SET ERRORLEVEL = 0" />
```

**PDB file not available on fresh build**

When run as a fresh build, the original PDB file for the main project is not available when the copy command is run - robocopy reports file not available. They exist for the dependent projects, possibly because they are already built.

So when is the PDB file generated? Is it being made after the post-build command? Is there some target I can put in `AfterTargets` get this command to run after rather than `PostBuildEvent`?

**File is not copied**

This happens when I run the build a second time, so that the original PDB file *does* exist.

I have a robocopy command (I've tried copy and xcopy as well in my desperation) that works when run manually:

```
(robocopy $(TargetDir)bin\ $(TargetDir) MyProject.pdb) ^& IF %ERRORLEVEL% LSS 8 SET ERRORLEVEL = 0
```

When run as a post-build event, it even reports that the file was copied:

```
Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
 Dirs :         1         0         1         0         0         0
Files :         1         1         0         0         0         0
Bytes :    57.5 k    57.5 k         0         0         0         0
Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
```

But the file is not there. Is the directory getting cleared at some point after the file copy? As above, my best guess is I need some other `AfterTargets` set.

This seems like a pretty common thing to do....am I missing something, or is this because it's a Functions project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is a `_GenerateFunctionsPostBuild` target (not sure exactly where it comes from) but using that has fixed it

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="_GenerateFunctionsPostBuild">
<Exec Command="(robocopy $(TargetDir)bin\ $(TargetDir) *) ^&amp; IF %25ERRORLEVEL%25 LSS 8 SET ERRORLEVEL = 0" />
```